# App uses rest services which use GPL library

Tags: web-applications, gpl, android

I'm developing an app (for Android) which uses data received from my rest services. These services use also GPL libraries: if I have correctly understood, if a server side web application uses GPL libraries it has not requirements to release its source code as GPL. Has my app code any requirements if it uses this rest services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely mistaken.

Your thinking revolves around typical web apps that use any old web browser, making the two pieces independent works.

Your situation most likely is actually a single work, with both pieces completely useless without the other. In that situation, the FSF maintains it all is a single work with the Android piece also subject to the requirements of the GPL.

That is the FSF's position, which to my knowledge hasn't been tested in court. Ignore at your own peril.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And if my rest services use LGPL libraries what are my requirements?

Comment: Would the down voter please explain how my answer is incorrect or unhelpful?

Comment: @Teo: one of terms of the LGPL is that users of the software are able to replace the LGPL libraries with modified version if they desire. The short answer for the LGPL is the same as the GPL, the long answer is the complexities of that and answering it is beyond the scope of permissible copyright/legal questions on this site.

Comment: Yes, I understand the complexities. Just another thing: do these requirements (for use of GPL and LGPL libraries in rest services) apply only to distributed binaries? In this case they are just app binary and not rest services. Is it correct?

Comment: @Teo: read the licenses yourself and read the GNU FAQ. The licenses are in plain language. Any questions beyond what can be answered by reading those things are beyond the scope of this site.